# Return only matching portion of regular expression

Tags: regex, r

I have:

```
> pattern
[1] "(/[[:digit:]]{4}/)"
```

so I want to extract only the matching portions...the digits plus the /.../. Here's what I tried:

```
> gsub(pattern, '\\1', grep(pattern, c("t3tg3wgw/5764/", "ggg", "grsgs/gwgew/5656/bfsbs"), value=TRUE))
[1] "t3tg3wgw/5764/"         "grsgs/gwgew/5656/bfsbs"
```

However this still returns letters attached to the actual match that do not themselves match the regex. How can I extract only `/5764/` and `/5656/`?

Comment: @akrun thanks for the info. I'm looking for a way with base R.

Comment: In that case `gregxpr/regmatches` can be used

Answer (score 0):

We could extract the pattern `/` followed by one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) followed by `/` using `str_extract_all` from `library(stringr)` to output a `list`, which can be `unlist`ed to convert to `vector`

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(v1, '/[0-9]+/'))
#[1] "/5764/" "/5656/"
```

Or we use the same pattern and using `regmatches/gregexpr` from `base R`

```
unlist(regmatches(v1, gregexpr('/[0-9]+/',v1)))
#[1] "/5764/" "/5656/"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c("t3tg3wgw/5764/", "ggg", "grsgs/gwgew/5656/bfsbs")
```

Comment: yeah just realized that and remodified my answer. you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the pattern to `.*(/[[:digit:]]{4}/).*`